# How to Insert Data From Muliple tables of 1 database to single table of another database in sql

Tags: database, sql-server-2014, database-trigger

I have Two Databases `TEST1` and `TEST2`.
`TEST1` has 4 tables and `TEST2` has 1 Table.
Now, 
I want to have a Trigger Method which Takes data from 4 Tables of 1st Database and inserts into that into single table in 2nd Database.

So far, I have looked into Function that gets executed on Trigger but didn't seem to work.

Thanks for Efforts.

Comment: This can be done. But this screams XY problem.

Comment: What version of `SQL-Server`? Depending on the version, different options may or may not be available.

Comment: The version is Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Cross-database access from a trigger is a bad idea. For starters, you run into security issues that can only be fixed by doing other things that are bad ideas. What's more, a trigger is defined on one table, not four -- and having four triggers do the same thing is another bad idea. What are your actual requirements -- do things need to happen whenever anything changes in those four tables, in real time, as part of a transaction? Can you tolerate delay, if so, how much? Does it need to be ironclad because it's for auditing purposes, or can you tolerate failure?

Comment: Sorry for providing less info. Let suppose For TEST1, I have Tables as Followed, VARIABLES, DATA, TIME, BATCH. Now the TEST2 has a table called Result. When the data gets updated from the outside source to TEST1, I want to take the updated value from each table and make a row of that values which would have the same number of columns as table on TEST2 has.

Comment: @KaushikShah With version 2014 of `sql-server`, you could use the `Linked Server` approach, this article gives good information on how to set up a linked server with security tips (https://sqljana.wordpress.com/2017/06/16/sql-server-curse-of-linked-server-security-and-the-fix-pass-through-authentication/)

Comment: @RyanWilson Thanks for the article. In this case, I am still using the same server but its just 2 different databases. The article is perhaps for 2 different servers.

Comment: @KaushikShah That is correct, linked server is just as you said for two different servers. I misunderstood.